# How to create add an array to a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to merge an array into another.  If a business is a child of it's sector.

My aim is to create a array that looks like this:

```
[0] => Array (
    [sector] => 198
    [business] => Array (
        [0] => 201
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [sector] => 178
    [business] => Array (
        [0] => 181
        [1] => 182
        )
    )
```

I currently have this:

```
[0] => Array (
    [sector] => 198
    )
[1] => Array (
    [sector] => 178
    )
```

and this (business ids):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 201
)

Array
(
    [0] => 181
    [1] => 182
)
```

I need to nest these under sector.

This is what I have at the moment

```
        $targets = array();
        foreach ($taxonomy['sector'] as $sectorKey=>$sector) {
            $getSectorTerm = get_term_by('slug', $sector, 'sector');
            $getSectorId = $getSectorTerm->term_id;

            $targets[] = array('sector'=>$getSectorId, 'business'=>[]);


            foreach ($taxonomy['business'] as $keyBusiness=>$businesses) {
                foreach ($businesses as $key => $business) {
                    $getBusinessTerm = get_term_by('slug', $business, 'sector');
                    $getBusinessId = $getBusinessTerm->term_id;

                    $getParentTerm = get_term( $getBusinessTerm, 'sector' );
                    $businessParentId = $getParentTerm->parent; 

                    if ($businessParentId == $getSectorId) {
                        array_push($targets, $getBusinessId);
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        print_r($targets);
        die;
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sector] => 198
        )

    [1] => 201

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sector] => 178
        )

    [3] => 181
    [4] => 182

)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output now?

Comment: Soz just added the output above.

Answer (score 1):

It should be work like this:-

```
    $targets = array();
    foreach ($taxonomy['sector'] as $sectorKey=>$sector) {
        $getSectorTerm = get_term_by('slug', $sector, 'sector');
        $getSectorId = $getSectorTerm->term_id;

        $target_array = array('sector'=>$getSectorId, 'business'=>[]);


        foreach ($taxonomy['business'] as $keyBusiness=>$businesses) {
            foreach ($businesses as $key => $business) {
                $getBusinessTerm = get_term_by('slug', $business, 'sector');
                $getBusinessId = $getBusinessTerm->term_id;

                $getParentTerm = get_term( $getBusinessTerm, 'sector' );
                $businessParentId = $getParentTerm->parent; 

                if ($businessParentId == $getSectorId) {
                    $target_array['business'][] = $getBusinessId;
                }
            }

        }
        $targets[] = $target_array;
    }

    print_r($targets);
    die;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll keep current structure of array, it would be hard to populate the array with subarrays. It requires additional loop through the aray to find a certain sector value.
Are you able to change array structure to make it more compact and accessible? I mean that compact array has keys equal to sectors ID, and values are array of business IDs. For example like this:

```
[198] => Array (
        [0] => 201
)
[178] => Array (
        [0] => 181
        [1] => 182
)


$targets = array();
foreach ($taxonomy['sector'] as $sectorKey=>$sector) {
    $getSectorTerm = get_term_by('slug', $sector, 'sector');
    $getSectorId = $getSectorTerm->term_id;

    $targets[ $getSectorId ] = [];


    foreach ($taxonomy['business'] as $keyBusiness=>$businesses) {
        foreach ($businesses as $key => $business) {
            $getBusinessTerm = get_term_by('slug', $business, 'sector');
            $getBusinessId = $getBusinessTerm->term_id;

            $getParentTerm = get_term( $getBusinessTerm, 'sector' );
            $businessParentId = $getParentTerm->parent; 

            if ($businessParentId == $getSectorId) {
                $targets[ $getSectorId ][] = $getBusinessId;
            }

        }

    }
}

print_r($targets);
die;
```

To get a table:

```
foreach($targets as $sector => $businesses) {
    echo "Sector ID: $sector<br>";
    foreach( $businesses as $business ) {
        echo "Business ID: $business<br>";
    }
}
```